# Loop script for invoice creation

Tags: magento-1.9, order-status, programmatically, create-invoice

Recently I have migrated our website. I have imported the orders however they all by default were changed to complete and no invoice was created.

The main problem is that it works great with one order number, more order numbers comma-delimited get me the PHP error.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in /home/alphalasulaco/public_html/inv-cre.php on line 5
```

I have compiled the following script to change the order to processing and allow invoice creation.

```
<?php
require_once('./app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$orderNumbers = 100124858,100124857;

$order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($orderNumbers);

$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('increment_id', array('in' => $orderNumbers));

foreach ($collection as $order) {
            $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING)
                ->setStatus(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING)
                ->save();
}

try {
if($order->canInvoice())
{ 
$invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice();

if ($invoice->getTotalQty()) { 

$invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_OFFLINE);
$invoice->register();
$transaction = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
->addObject($invoice)
->addObject($invoice->getOrder()); 
$transaction->save();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Invoice Created Successfully.'); 
}else{
 Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Can not create invoice without Product Quantities'); 
 }

}else{
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Can not create invoice'); 
}
}
catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
 echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the error gives it away:

```
$orderNumbers = 100124858,100124857;
```

Should be:

```
$orderNumbers = array(100124858,100124857);
```

Then to get your code working you need to delete the following line:

```
$order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($orderNumbers);
```

And move the entire `try/catch` code block inside the collection `foreach` loop.

Comment: Would you know how to force invoice number to be the same as the order number, using the above script?

Comment: @damek132 well that's a different issue, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965721/magento-create-an-invoice-with-invoice-number-order-number

Comment: Right, it came to my attention that there is a extension which keeps the order number as invoice number, shipment number and credit memo number. I am hoping that with that plugin I will be able to achieve this using the script.

Comment: @damek132 feel free to upvote and mark your question as answered if my post helped you in your original question.